# Two MQTT IoT agents - which one to use?

Tags: fiware

Why are there two MQTT agents:

1. https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-mqtt
2. https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus

Isn't this duplicated work?

Which one should be used?

BR,

Drasko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-mqtt is a full-working agent that bridges context information using MQTT into NGSI, developed in Node JS. This software is ready to go out of the box, but only supports MQTT (there are other protocols supported in other IoTAgents).

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus is a C++ development framework. This means that you can use it to fit to your specific protocol needs (could be MQTT, but could be other) and using C++ as programming language. This software requires that you implement several functionalities and will not do much out of the box, but offers maximun flexibility.